# How to move recently viewed products?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to move recently viewed products. I moved it to the product page with this code in catalog.xml
`<reference name="content">
     <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
  </reference>`
 but it's on the top of the page and i need it after the description. Which is in the bottom. I'm using magento 1.9. Please tell me what file to use if you have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to the templates? You can make it appear wherever you'd like by editing the `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file.

First, change your reference tag to `<reference name="product.info">`.

Then go to your `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file and add this where you'd like it to show up:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('recently_viewed') ?>
```

If you want it to show up after the description, add it after (or before):

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

This way you can add it exactly where you'd like. BUT if you don't have access to that, I'll edit my answer to add a way to do it with just XML.